# document: MultipartBody.Part? Value is not being sent to the server

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created the document but the value of document does not reach the server.
All others have values, only the value of document is missing.
The same API is called from web and it works fine.

```
private fun createAssignment() {
    val subject = subjectSpinner.selectedItem?.let { s -> s as SubjectModel }
    val teacherId: Long = viewModel.user?.id!!
    val sectionBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.get("text/plain"), section.id.toString())
    val subjectBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.get("text/plain"), subject?.id.toString())
    val titleBody =
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), titleEditText.text?.trim().toString())
    val descriptionBody =
        RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
            descriptionEditText.text?.trim().toString()
        )
    val startDateBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.get("text/plain"), assignmentDate)
    val endDateBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.get("text/plain"), submissionDate)
    val teacherBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.get("text/plain"), teacherId.toString())
    val statusBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.get("text/plain"), "0")


    loadingProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    createButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

    val role = viewModel.role?.slug

    if (image != null) {
        image?.let {
            val file = File(it.path)
            val url = file.absolutePath
            val fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap()
            val mimeType = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor("file://$url")
            val documentBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), file)
            val document = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", it.name, documentBody)
```

and service

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/assignment")
fun create(
    @Header("role") role: String,
    @Part("title") title: RequestBody,
    @Part("description") description: RequestBody,
    @Part("subject_id") subjectId: RequestBody,
    @Part("teacher_id") teacherId: RequestBody,
    @Part("section_id") sectionId: RequestBody,
    @Part("assignment_date") assignmentDate: RequestBody,
    @Part("submission_date") submissionDate: RequestBody,
    @Part("status") status: RequestBody,
    @Part document: MultipartBody.Part?
): Call<AssignmentResponse>
```

Comment: use @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> file

Comment: I am sending a single document. That does not work.

Comment: where do you define/initialise `image`? Where do you call `create` and which arguments are you passing?

Comment: I found my problem and its solution. The problem was on this line :                     val document = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", it.name, documentBody)                                                                                                                     I should have used "document" instead of "image". That's working as a key. Now it is working fine.